# AS3 Argument count mismatch

Tags: actionscript-3, arguments

I don't understand why only one argument is getting passed through. The way it looks to me I'm passing 2, but flash doesn't see it that way. Why? I am trying to build a simple calculator where you put the first number (num1) in a text field, the second number (num2) in another text field, click an add/subtract/multiply/divide button and have the answer appear in a third text field. Here I am getting

ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on CalculatorLab/addme(). Expected 2, got 1.

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class CalculatorLab extends MovieClip {


        public function CalculatorLab() {
            // constructor code
            var num1:Number = 0;
            var num2:Number = 0;

            addbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addme);
            subtractbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, subtractme);
            multiplybtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, multiplyme);
            dividebtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, divideme);

        }

        function addme(num1, num2):void { 
            num1txt.text = String(num1);
            num2txt.text = String(num2);
            var answer:Number = num1 + num2;
            trace(answer);
                    answertxt.text = String(answer);
            }

        function subtractme(num1, num2):void { 
            num1txt.text = String(num1);
            num2txt.text = String(num2);
            var answer:Number = num1 - num2;
            trace(answer);
                    answertxt.text = String(answer);
            }

        function multiplyme(num1, num2):void { 
            num1txt.text = String(num1);
            num2txt.text = String(num2);
            var answer:Number = num1 * num2;
            trace(answer);
                    answertxt.text = String(answer);
            }

        function divideme(num1, num2):void { 
            num1txt.text = String(num1);
            num2txt.text = String(num2);
            var answer:Number = num1 / num2;
            trace(answer);
                    answertxt.text = String(answer);
            }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event listeners are passed one argument, which is the event object (MouseEvent in your case).

So your code should look a bit different

```
function addme(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    var num1:Number = Number(num1txt.text);
    var num2:Number = Number(num2txt.text);
    var answer:Number = num1 + num2;
    trace(answer);
    answertxt.text = String(answer);
}
```

All you need to do is change other 3 event handlers in the same way. You can also remove the local variables num1 and num2 from the constructor code since they are not used anywhere.

Comment: That gives me 4 syntax errors on Line 19,20,21 and 22 which say  1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before colon   where what i had before gave no syntax errors and only an output argument error that says expecting 2 arguments and got 1, after I put a number in the first box, a number in the second box and clicked the + button

Comment: Here is an additional question. Why can't I move the num1 and num2 var's outside of the function and use them as global variables? When I try that I get an error that says TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at CalculatorLab()

Comment: You should be able to. You could define them as class variables as well. Please accept the answer if it helped you solve your original problem. Edit: You just did, thanks!